# Linux printer proxy server

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, printing, printer, raspberry-pi

I have an old laser printer I found for $7 at a thrift store (Dell 3100).  However, the drivers are not compatible with Windows 8.1, which my main PC runs.  (I tried to install it anyways and it messed up my computer's print system).

I also have a Raspberry Pi.  I would like to use it to print from my Windows PC, as well as several Linux machines.

To my understanding, CUPS still requires printer drivers for network printing through another machine.

I need something that doesn't require drivers on the client machines.  How can I do this?  One possibility I can think of is a web service where I can upload documents for printing.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Dell printer on one of the Linux machines - I'm almost certain you'll find support for the printer in Linux.

Then you can access the printer over the network, using Cups from Linux machines, or using Samba on the Windows machine.

I had a similar problem time ago, where the Windows machine didn't have a driver (anymore) for a Epson professional scanner. So I connected the scanner on a Linux machine, and managed it from the Windows machine...